# Client program for continuous talking to an echo server in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, server

I'm an absolute beginner in nodejs. I've created an echo server in nodejs. And honestly i would say, i followed few youtube tutorials for this. There is nothing wrong with the server code. I want to create a client program to talk to this server. I dont want to use `telnet client` or any such thing. And by 'continuous' I mean the server and client should stay connected till I close the server manually using `ctrl+c`. Here's my server.js.

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser=require('body-parser');
var server=express();
server.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
server.use(bodyParser.json());
server.post("/", function (req, res) {
  console.log("I got: "+req.body.message);
  res.send(req.body.message);
});
server.listen(3000, function() {
  console.log("Express echo server is listening on port 3000");
})
```

I do not say *hey write the code for me*. In fact I tried also. Here's my client.js

```
var request = require('request');
var arg="";
process.argv.slice(2).forEach(function (val, index, array) {
  arg+=val +" ";
});
request.post({
  url: "http://localhost:3000",
  json: true,
  body: {message: arg}
}, function (err, response, body) {
  if(!err && response.statusCode==200) {
    console.log(body);
  }
});
```

But client sends data only once that too using command line argument.

`node client.js hello`

PS: I'm using these npm modules `express`, `body-parser` and `request`

Comment: In the `request.post` callback you're declaring  the error argument as `arr`, yet you're performing a check below on a variable named `err`. This looks like just a typo.

Comment: @NikKyriakides Sorry for the typo.

Comment: The error should change as well, @Tanzeel

Comment: @AritraChakraborty Yes I corrected the typo. Client is working absolutely fine now. But i want to create a client that talks continuously with the server. While my version closes down immediately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you made is a **HTTP Server** using express.

The server runs alright, but the client closes because you are only making a single request to the server. So what is happening is expected behaviour.

So, there are multiple ways, 
The most simple way would be, using `readline` or some other to continuously read the lines that you type And sending it to the server:

```
const request = require('request');
const readline = require("readline").createInterface({
  input: process.stdin,
  output: process.stdout
});

readline.setPrompt('msg: ');
readline.prompt();

readline.on('line', function(input) {
  if(input === 'close') return readline.close();
  request.post({
    url: "http://localhost:3000",
    json: true,
    body: {message: input}
  }, function (err, response, body) {
    readline.prompt();
  });
}).on('close', function() {
    console.log('Closed');
    process.exit(0);
});
```

**But** the proper way would be using `sockets` like `socket-io` to make a persistent connection between the server and client. Read [here](https://socket.io/docs/#Using-with-Express) for more information.

Comment: This is good. But client need to print that echoed text also. We can do this `console.log(body)` in `function (err, response, body) {
    readline.prompt(); console.log(body) }`. Good job @aritra